# "Advanced" App Store search

Tags: ios-appstore

I would like to search the iPhone app store in such a way that I only see results that *don't* offer an in-app purchase. I know that Apple offers a [data feed](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/blog/enterprise-partner-feed.html) of all the App Store's data, so in principle a service could exist that would allow this. However, having tried all the App Store search engines I know of (uQurey, AppShopper, AppAdvice, 148apps), it seems that none of them offer this kind of specific customised search.

So my question is whether there is an App Store search service that allows such specific queries as this.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer, if it helped you out. I'm sorry there's no better solution.

Comment: @Rob I upvoted it, but my experience on Stack Exchange is that accepting an answer tends to discourage further answers, so I prefer to keep it open. It may be that there's no currently published query for this purpose now, but in the future there might be, and if someone posts an answer about it I'll accept that one.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way now: https://appapp.io/us/has_iap=false/search

(Full disclosure - I made it)

Comment: Is there a version of this site for macOS?

Comment: @chb Not right now - would you want one?

Comment: Yes! I, for one, would be grateful, though it's possible that I'm in a minority of macOS users. I'm having a hard time understanding the App Store (and [this question is not being received well](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316055/macos-app-store-alternative)). Do you have any insights into why it is the way it is?

Comment: @chb: Apple makes a commission of all purchases made through the App Store, including in-app ones. Aggressively monetized apps are a pain for the end user, but they make more money. If it were easy to filter out these apps, the App Store would be much more consumer-friendly, but unfortunately, the store is controlled by a company that has more to gain from making predatory developers hard for consumers to avoid, than they do from making them easy to avoid. So it doesn’t at all surprise me that this option isn’t there, as nice as it would be if Apple sided with end users over developers more.

Comment: Free apps are not in that appapp platform.

Answer (score 1):

In short: No, there's currently no query for that. At least, none of them are published.
I doubt Apple want to display those without in-App purchases, as they make them money when people buy it.

I seriously hope someone will proof me wrong in the nearby-future, but currently there's no option available for this. I've been searching around for a while for those filter-criteria.

Comment: You're probably right. (I'll leave the question open though, just in case.) I'm not sure it really is in Apple's interests, though. If the problem of apps (and games in particular) that appear free/cheap but actually aren't gets too bad, I'll just buy my way out of the iOS ecosystem, and eventually I'm sure others will too. But I guess that's Apple's choice to make...

Comment: It is in user's interest and that is something Apple should listen to. If they ignore this higher principle, their value to users will collapse.